# How does navigation work in a Spring Boot and Angular Application?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I am having an app whose backend is done using Spring Boot framework and Angular in frontend.
Let us say we have a routing in Angular such that on a page Page1 we have a link that takes us to Page2. Now page2 fetches data from backend via a Post method.
All works fine but refreshing Page2 doesn't (as on refreshing Page2 a Get request is invoked and not Post as per Networks Tab in dev tools).
I am thinking that when I try to refresh the page let us say url being https://app1.com/fruit/Page2 which came after clicking on the link for Page2, it tries to access the controller method of backend which of course does not exist. We wanted Angular component Page2 but it is coming only when we click the link. What should we do to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use `useHash` as true.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
...
const routes: Routes = [//routes in here];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```